# Oracle issue in group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I know this question is asked by many people. But I still couldn't figure out why this is happening. Couldn't understand this logic.

I have a table mytesttable with columns `id`, `company_name` and `employee_name`.

I am trying to get the employee details grouping them with respect to company name. So I used the below query:

```
select * 
from mytesttable 
group by company_name;
```

But I get the below issue:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 28 Column: 2
```

Now I have tried putting count(1) in select along with my columns, tried grouping using 2 columns etc. Still the same issue. Can anyone explain me how to achieve this?

Because this is a simple group by. Logic seems to be right, but wondering  why it's not fetching me the result.

Comment: When using `group by` either you have to put the columns in `group by` clause or aggregate function then only you can select them. Read it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: That query makes no sense. Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is:

```
select *
from mytesttable
group by company_name;
```

The `*` expands to all the columns.  So this becomes:

```
select company_name, col1, col2, col3, . . .  -- your question doesn't specify the column names
from mytesttable
group by company_name;
```

When you specify the `group by`, you are specifying that there is one row per `company_name` in the result set.  The other columns are normally filled with *aggregation* functions, such as `MIN()`, `SUM()`, or `LISTAGG()`.

What value should be chosen for `col1`?  In general, SQL does not attempt to answer this question.  Instead, it returns a syntax error.  This is not Oracle-specific.  This is the definition of the language.

What you probably want is:

```
select company_name, count(*) as num_employees
from mytesttable
group by company_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

In group by clause you have to put all selected columns. As you select all but given only one column in group by as a result it thrown error, but if you simply try like this way it will work. Actually group by used for aggregated function

```
select company_name, count(*) from mytesttable group by company_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mis-understand what `GROUP BY` does?

It doesn't put all similar records next to each other, that's `ORDER BY`.  What `GROUP BY` does is to collapse all similar records in to the same row, to allow aggregate calculations like `SUM()` and `MIN()` and `COUNT()`, etc.

So, two examples using the same input...

```
 id | company_name | employee_name
----+--------------+---------------
 1  | zzz          | aaa
 2  | xxx          | bbb
 3  | yyy          | ccc
 4  | zzz          | ddd
 5  | xxx          | eee
```

Using `ORDER BY`...

```
SELECT * FROM mytesttable ORDER BY company_name, employee_name

 id | company_name | employee_name
----+--------------+---------------
 2  | xxx          | bbb
 5  | xxx          | eee
 3  | yyy          | ccc
 1  | zzz          | aaa
 4  | zzz          | ddd
```

Using `GROUP BY`...

```
SELECT
  company_name,
  COUNT(*)       number_of_employees,
  MAX(id)        highest_id_in_company
FROM
  mytesttable
GROUP BY
  company_name
ORDER BY
  company_name

 company_name | number_of_employees | highest_id_in_company
--------------+---------------------+-----------------------
 xxx          | 2                   | 5
 yyy          | 1                   | 3
 zzz          | 2                   | 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use group-by expression,you have to use aggregate functions such as max,min,average,count in select statements.

For example;

```
select count(*),company_name,employee_name
  from mytesttable
 group by company_name,employee_name
 order by company_name;
```